# Add a new dictionary to a list of dictionary python

Tags: python

So this is my list of dictionaries:

```
array_of_dictionaries = [{
    "name": "Budi",
    "age": 23,
    "test_scores": [100.0, 98.0, 89.0]
},
{
    "name": "Charlie",
    "age": 24,
    "test_scores": [90.0, 100.0]
}]
```

And this is my code:

```
def add_student(dictionary_list, student_dictionary):
  for element in dictionary_list:
    dict_copy = student_dictionary.copy()
    dictionary_list.append(dict_copy)
    return student_dictionary

updated_dictionary = add_student(array_of_dictionaries, { "name": "Doddy", "age": 13, "test_scores": [100.0, 100.0, 100.0] })
print(updated_dictionary)
```

The output I desire is:

```
[{'name': 'Budi', 'age': 10, 'test_scores': [100.0, 98.0, 89.0]}, {'name': 'Charlie', 'age': 12, 'test_scores': [90.0, 100.0]}, {'name': 'Doddy', 'age': 13, 'test_scores': [100.0, 100.0, 100.0]}]
```

But what I got is:

```
{'name': 'Doddy', 'age': 13, 'test_scores': [100.0, 100.0, 100.0]}
```

Comment: But why `{'name': 'Doddy', 'age': 13, 'test_scores': [100.0, 100.0, 100.0]}` is not there in your array_of_Dictionaries?

Comment: That's just for that codes. I intend to not just add the dictionary you mentioned

Comment: @OliverRobie Yes I believe the OP has got confused and vastly over complicated the solution.

Comment: Yeah you guys right. I didn't realize my logic makes my code not necessary complicated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is very confused. Ultimately what you want to do is append an element to a list.

I.e.

```
l = [1, 2, 3]
l.append(4)
#l = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

The element you want to append is dictionary type, rather than integer, but this does not affect the logic. The code for the function is then incredibly simple:

```
def add_student(dictionary_list, student_dictionary):
  dictionary_list.append(student_dictionary)
  return dictionary_list
```

This gives the desired output. (Of course it does not make a *copy* of the dictionary to be added, but you can modify this behaviour be appending `student_dictionary.copy()`).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a function if you want to perform update on same dictionary. You can directly add element.

```
newitem = { "name": "Doddy", "age": 13, "test_scores": [100.0, 100.0, 100.0] }
array_of_dictionaries.append(newitem)
```

Be careful with copy command with mutable object, otherwise you will see an unexpected behavior.